# JAVA преобразование типов внутри stream

Tags: java, java-stream

нужно принять поток интов и делитель, и вернуть Map<делимое, результат деления>

в Math.floorMod(number, divisor) ругается на то, что number - Object, хотя если просто считать через .map там будет число, подскажите пожалуйста почему так получается и как решить?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Collecting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collecting collecting = new Collecting();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            list.add(i);
        IntStream stream = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf);
        int res = collecting.oddSum(stream);
    }

  
    public Map<Integer, Integer> sumByRemainder(IntStream stream, int divisor) {
        return stream
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(number -> number, number -> (Math.floorMod(number, divisor))));
                //.map(number -> Math.floorMod(number, divisor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема глубже, `IntStream.collect()` принимает три параметра и не работает с обычным интерфейсом Collector.
Самое простое, что вы можете сделать, это преобразовать `IntStream` в `Stream<Integer>`.

```
return stream.mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                          number -> number, 
                          number -> Math.floorMod(number, divisor)
              ));
```